# Change color of back button

Tags: winrt-xaml

I am trying to change some of the default back button in WinRT but I am having trouble doing so. This is the xaml in StandardStyles.xaml

```
<!--
        BackButtonStyle is used to style a Button for use in the title area of a page.  Margins appropriate for
        the conventional page layout are included as part of the style.
    -->
    <Style x:Key="BackButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="48"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="48"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="36,0,36,36"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Symbol"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="56"/>
        <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="BackButton"/>
        <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="Back"/>
        <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.ItemType" Value="Navigation Button"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
                        <Grid Margin="-1,-16,0,0">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="BackgroundGlyph" Text="&#xE0A8;" Foreground="{StaticResource BackButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="NormalGlyph" Text="{StaticResource BackButtonGlyph}" Foreground="{StaticResource BackButtonForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="ArrowGlyph" Text="&#xE0A6;" Foreground="{StaticResource BackButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush}" Opacity="0"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Rectangle
                            x:Name="FocusVisualWhite"
                            IsHitTestVisible="False"
                            Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}"
                            StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                            StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                            Opacity="0"
                            StrokeDashOffset="1.5"/>
                        <Rectangle
                            x:Name="FocusVisualBlack"
                            IsHitTestVisible="False"
                            Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}"
                            StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                            StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                            Opacity="0"
                            StrokeDashOffset="0.5"/>

                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource BackButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource BackButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource BackButtonForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="ArrowGlyph"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            To="1"
                                            Duration="0"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="NormalGlyph"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            To="0"
                                            Duration="0"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            To="1"
                                            Duration="0"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            To="1"
                                            Duration="0"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I just want to set the color to black for every state. how can I do this while still maintaining the "Metro" arrow?

Comment: have you tried changing foreground property in the style ? You also have to change the value of foreground from all the storyboard also.

Comment: Ya that I know. But the foreground style is set to a common style which I can't find. :(

Comment: What do you mean by `common style` ? You can also edit default brushes like `BackButtonBackgroundThemeBrush`, `BackButtonDisabledForegroundThemeBrush`. See [this](http://metro.excastle.com/xaml-system-brushes) for all the brushes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two possible different approaches.

### Approach 1: create a specific style

The simplest solution is to set the colors directly in the `Style` to the desired hardcoded values like in the following code, this produces a black button:

```
<Style x:Key="BackButtonStyleBlack" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="48"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="48"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="36,0,36,36"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Symbol"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="56"/>
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="BackButton"/>
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="Back"/>
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.ItemType" Value="Navigation Button"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
                    <Grid Margin="-1,-16,0,0">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="BackgroundGlyph" Text="&#xE0A8;" Foreground="{StaticResource BackButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="NormalGlyph" Text="{StaticResource BackButtonGlyph}" Foreground="Black"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="ArrowGlyph" Text="&#xE0A6;" Foreground="White" Opacity="0"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Rectangle
                    x:Name="FocusVisualWhite"
                    IsHitTestVisible="False"
                    Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}"
                    StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                    StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                    Opacity="0"
                    StrokeDashOffset="1.5"/>
                    <Rectangle
                    x:Name="FocusVisualBlack"
                    IsHitTestVisible="False"
                    Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}"
                    StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                    StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                    Opacity="0"
                    StrokeDashOffset="0.5"/>

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource BackButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="ArrowGlyph"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                    To="1"
                                    Duration="0"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="NormalGlyph"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                    To="0"
                                    Duration="0"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                    To="1"
                                    Duration="0"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                    To="1"
                                    Duration="0"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This produces the following result on a `SeaGreen` background.
Normal
[image]

PointerOver
[image]

Pressed
[image]

### Approach 2: Override theme brushes

The other solution is to override the theme brushes used by the built-in style.
You have to do this in your App.xaml file like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <!-- 
                Styles that define common aspects of the platform look and feel
                Required by Visual Studio project and item templates
                -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Common/StandardStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackButtonForegroundThemeBrush" Color="Black" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush" Color="White" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush" Color="Black" />

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

And you can use the normal `BackButtonStyle` style on your page:

```
<Grid Background="SeaGreen">
    <Button Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}" />
</Grid>
```

This produces the same result as the other approach with much less code.
The big difference is that this solution changes the color scheme for every button using that style, and this can only be done **globally** in the App.xaml and cannot be used on a per-page basis.

Comment: Thanks Mark! This is exactly what I wanted. There's not much stuff online for WinRT yet, but this definitely helps a lot. Being an OOP programmer strictly makes it harder for me to make these type of apps. Now I spend most of my time on UI.

Answer (score 0):

I have tweaked this XAML for Windows 8.1. It is not the best solution but it does work.

```
<Style x:Key="ApplicationNavigationBackButtonNormalStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,4,12,4"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">                                 
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="3">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhite" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="1.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlack" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="0.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that it will match your request but I needed to make one page with LightTheme in the DarkTheme application.

```
RequestedTheme="Light"
```

Property of the page helped me. It mean that you can set the Theme for the entire Application and override for some specific page.